# Making H2O grid search deterministic

Tags: machine-learning, h2o, sparkling-water

In order to run the h2o `RandomDiscreteValueWalker[DRFParameters]` with deterministic results, is it sufficient to set the seed on the `DRFParameters` and the `RandomDiscreteValueSearchCriteria` ? I get non-deterministic results even when I have the seed fixed for these parameters?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.